# A panel switcher custom control for Winform in .net?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls

This is a .net winform UI question.

In many cases, we want to design an UI such that, you have several options, and based on the option you choose, a different detail UI is setup for you. For example, imagine a user registration: based on the location you pick, you may be asked to fill in different information. Normally, when I design the form for such a purpose, I will create an empty panel for place holding on the main form. And I will create one user control for each detail UI. When the form is loaded, I will create instances of the user controls (representing detail UI based on options) and dock them on the panel and hide the irrelevant ones. When a user changes her option (maybe via a dropdownlist or via a set of radio buttons), I programmatically decide which user control needs to be shown and rest to be hidden. All good so far.

But this solution has a problem, when you open your form in VS form designer, all you see is an empty panel and you have no idea what will be looked like when your user controls are filled in. If another programmer opens your form in designer, he will have no idea what's going on here, an empty panel? Then he has to go to your code and find out the user controls.

So, do we have a user control that behaves similar to tabcontrol so that all the user controls can be organized visually in designer during design time? Of course, you will say, then use tabcontrol. But obviously, the purpose is not the same as tabcontrol but rather a tabcontrol without the tab buttons on top. You may ask me to write few lines of code to hide the tab buttons on the tabcontrol. Yes, we can do that, but I find that after hiding the tab buttons, there will be some space around the tabcontrol and other controls outside it and the look is not ideal. And visually the tab buttons take extra space than the tabpages themselves so hiding them will give you some layout margin problem.

Is there a custom control developed by someone that achieve my purpose? I mean, come on, this is a common problem and I don't believe everyone leaves an empty panel on the form. There must be some better solution. And I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: +1, would be nice to have such a control. Unfortunately, I didn't find one yet. Writing one will get a bit tricky because you need to make it interact with VS designer correctly ...

Comment: Actually, if you have code to hide the tabcontrol buttons I would love to see that.

Answer (score 2):

> But this solution has a problem, when you open your form in VS form designer, all you see is an empty panel and you have no idea what will be looked like when your user controls are filled in. If another programmer opens your form in designer, he will have no idea what's going on here, an empty panel? Then he has to go to your code and find out the user controls.

We also do this same stuff all over the place.  Agreed if you keep adding your panels to the form your going to have this problem.  The easy answer is just don't do that.  Create a UserControl derived from Panel in your project.  Then in your form add the custom control.

Now you can design the form independently from the panels and you can design each panel in it's own window.  This solution creates a few more source files, but it's well worth it to separate the logic of forms in this way even if your not showing and hiding the panels.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I've found using a tabcontrol and hiding the tabs to be the best solution. There's some assistance [here](http://dotnetrix.co.uk/tabcontrol.htm), but you're right it's not ideal.